# FluentValidation for WP7 - Validating Simple Types (string)

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7, fluentvalidation

I have the following problem, I'm trying to use [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) in Windows Phone to validate if a string is a valid username.

The problem I have is that the validator value has the type `string` which has to be tested. In all the examples I can find it's always a property of the object that is being tested like this `RuleFor(customer => customer.Surname).NotEmpty();`

When I run this code I get the following error

Code:

```
public class UsernameValidator : AbstractValidator<string>
{
    public UsernameValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(username => username).NotNull().NotEmpty().WithMessage("Enter a username");
        RuleFor(username => username).Matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$").WithMessage("Only letters and numbers");
        RuleFor(username => username).Length(3, 30).WithMessage("Minimum length is 3");
    }
}
```

Error:

```
FluentValidation for WP7 can only be used with expressions that reference public properties, ie x => x.SomeProperty
   at FluentValidation.Internal.Extensions.CompilePropertyGetterExpression(LambdaExpression expression, Type delegateType)
   at FluentValidation.Internal.Extensions.Compile[TDelegate](Expression`1 expression)
   at FluentValidation.Internal.PropertyRule`1.Create[TProperty](Expression`1 expression, Func`1 cascadeModeThunk)
   at FluentValidation.AbstractValidator`1.RuleFor[TProperty](Expression`1 expression)
   at WorldChat.ViewModels.Validators.UsernameValidator..ctor()
   at WorldChat.ViewModels.RegisterViewModel.get_ErrorUsername()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.InternalGetValue(PropertyInfo thisProperty, Object obj, Object[] index, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
   at System.Windows.CLRPropertyListener.get_Value()
   at System.Windows.PropertyAccessPathStep.ConnectToPropertyInSource(Boolean isSourceCollectionViewCurrentItem)
   at System.Windows.PropertyAccessPathStep.ConnectToProperty()
   at System.Windows.PropertyAccessPathStep.ReConnect(Object newSource)
   at System.Windows.PropertyPathListener.ReConnect(Object source)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SourceAcquired()
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.System.Windows.IDataContextChangedListener.OnDataContextChanged(Object sender, DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.DataContextChanged(Object sender, DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnAncestorDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.NotifyDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnAncestorDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.NotifyDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnTreeParentUpdated(DependencyObject newParent, Boolean bIsNewParentAlive)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateTreeParent(IManagedPeer oldParent, IManagedPeer newParent, Boolean bIsNewParentAlive, Boolean keepReferenceToParent)
   at MS.Internal.FrameworkCallbacks.ManagedPeerTreeUpdate(IntPtr oldParentElement, IntPtr parentElement, IntPtr childElement, Byte bIsParentAlive, Byte bKeepReferenceToParent, Byte bCanCreateParent)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MeasureNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MeasureOverrideNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MeasureOverrideNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationFrame.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround, it requires you to have a extra string wrapper class.

ValidationString.cs

```
public class ValidationString
{
    public string value { get; set; }

    public ValidationString(string value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

In the username validator class I add a static method IsUsername

```
public class UsernameValidator : AbstractValidator<ValidationString>
{
    public UsernameValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(username => username.value).NotNull().NotEmpty().WithMessage("Enter a username");
        RuleFor(username => username.value).Matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$").WithMessage("Only letters and numbers");
        RuleFor(username => username.value).Length(3, 30).WithMessage("Minimum length is 3");
    }

    internal static bool IsUsername(string value)
    {
        return new UsernameValidator().Validate(new ValidationString(value)).IsValid;
    }
}
```

And now I will be both able to use this UsernameValidator on a string as well as I'm still able to use it another validater, for example a registration validator

```
public class RegisterValidator : AbstractValidator<User>
{
    public RegisterValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(user => user.Username).Must(UsernameValidator.IsUsername);
        // some more rules
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use your UsernameValidator in other validation classes you can leave the `IsUsername` method out.

Comment: It is possible without the extra wrapper class, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

What about making a dummy class whose only member is the thing to test ? (Well, say one member for each type of data) :

```
public class ForYourTestsOnly
{
    public string MyString { get; set;}
    public int MyInt32 { get; set;}
    //And so on...
}
```

And then :

```
RuleFor(test => test.MyString)
```

(I confess I know nothing about FluentValidation, but if it's the only way to have it work, I suppose I would search in that direction...)

Comment: I came up with the same idea but than the next problem comes when I want to user for example the `UsernameValidator` in a `RegisterationValidator` which wants to apply the `UsernameValidator` to a string property.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with

```
RuleFor(username => username)
```

is that Fluent Validation cannot extract the property name. Fluent Validation expects to validate properties, so it tries to extract the property name from the expression tree in the `RuleFor()` argument. Since your expression does not mention a property, this fails.

You can prohibit FV from trying that by specifying the property explicitly. This works even if that property does not exist, because FV needs it only to report validation errors, as far as I understand it.

So the following worked for me, **without** an additional `ValidationString` wrapper class:

```
public class StringNotEmptyValidator : AbstractValidator<string>
{
    public StringNotEmptyValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(str => str).NotEmpty().OverridePropertyName("StringValue");
    }
}
```

This is example validates that a string is not empty. For your username validation case, the validator would look something like that (I didn't test this, but the concept is the same):

```
public class UsernameValidator : AbstractValidator<string>
{
    public UsernameValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(username => username).NotNull().NotEmpty().WithMessage("Enter a username").OverridePropertyName("UsernameValue");
        RuleFor(username => username).Matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$").WithMessage("Only letters and numbers").OverridePropertyName("UsernameValue");
        RuleFor(username => username).Length(3, 30).WithMessage("Minimum length is 3").OverridePropertyName("UsernameValue");
    }
}
```

Comment: What you just did here is the exact problem, FluentValidation in combination with Windows Phone 7 doesn't support the `username -> username` Linq, it requires a property of the object.

Comment: I see, seems my assumption that the problem is the same on the full framework was wrong. Then my solution solves just my problem, not yours, sorry :-)